# How do you access int arrays in java methods

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to declare a 2D array of integers, set its size in the constructor, and change the array's values in a method. When I compile this , I get "Cannot store to int array because "this.a" is null". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class arrays {
    int[][] a;

    public arrays(){
        int[][] a = new int[10][10];
    }
    public void m(){
        a[0][0] = 1;
        System.out.println(a[0][0]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        arrays Ar = new arrays();
        Ar.m();
    }
}
```

Comment: In method `arrays()`, remove the `int[][]` from `int[][] a = new int[10][10];`. --- A remark on the code: class names should be written in `CamelCase`, while variable names should be written in `camelCase` (`arrays Ar = new arrays()` -> `Arrays ar = new Arrays()`).

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names should be written in PascalCase (starting with uppercase) and variable names are written in camelCase (starting with lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

> ```java
> int[][] a = new int[10][10];
> ```

This is a combination of `int[][] a;` and `a = new int[10][10];` - `int[][] a;` **declares a new variable**. It has the same name as your field, and thus now two different things, both named `a`, are in 'scope'; the local variable 'wins' - `a = new int[10][10];` creates a new array and then assigns a reference to it to your **local variable** named `a`, not to the field named `a`. The constructor then ends, and all local variables are tossed away, because that's what always happens to local variables once a method/constructor exits: They disappear. In other words, you've created a new array but nothing is referring to; your field named `a` is not pointing at it because you didn't change that.

Just `a = new int[10][10];` will get the job done, as now there is no local variable also named `a` and thus `a` now refers to the field you have.

Or, even simpler, get rid of your constructor entirely, and initialize your array as you declare it:

```java
public class Arrays {
    int[][] a = new int[10][10];
    
    public void m() {
        a[0][0] = 1;
        System.out.println(a[0][0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays ar = new Arrays();
        ar.m();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but Initializations should be kept inside the constructor.

Comment: @wolfenblut that is, literally, as per the JLS spec, a load of hogwash.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about scoping.

1- You have a **property** called `int[][] a` in your class.

2- You have another `int[][] a`, which is a **local variable** in your constructor because you defined another int[][].

So, as @Turing85 said,just remove int[][] type definition inside your constructor and that line should be `a = new int[10][10];`

Additional information:

When you define another int[][] a in your constructor, there is more than one **a**. While assigning new int[10][10] to a, the closest one in terms of scope(which is inside the constructor) is used. It may be useful for you to exercise scoping.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the size before you are initializing the array

```
public class CustomArrays {
    int[][] a = new int[10][10];

    public void m(){
        a[0][0] = 1;
        System.out.println(a[0][0]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CustomArrays Ar = new CustomArrays();
        Ar.m();
    }
}
```

or this

```
public class CustomArrays {
    int[][] a = new int[10][10];

   CustomArrays() {
      a[0][0]=1;
   }

    public void m(){  
        System.out.println(a[0][0]);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CustomArrays Ar = new CustomArrays();
        Ar.m();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomArrays {
    int[][] a;

    public CustomArrays() {
         a = new int[10][10];
         a[0][0] = 1;
    }

    public void m() {

        System.out.println(this.a[0][0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomArrays Ar = new CustomArrays();
        Ar.m();
    }
}
```

all work.